# How to add non-zero elements to noise?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array and a noise function.

```
def gaussian_noise(X,sigma=0.1):
    noise = np.random.normal(0, sigma, X.shape)
    return X + noise
```

**How to add some noise to non zero element?**
For example:

```
# input an array
a = array([[1, 0, 3],
           [2, 5, 0],
           [0, 0, 7]])
b = gaussian_noise(a)
```

**Output:**

```
b = array([[ 0.83781175, 0.,  2.99969046],
           [ 1.92693919,  4.85350012,  0.],
           [0.,  0.,  7.04896986]])
```

How can I modify my function?

Comment: You're code produces a 3x3 matrix and it does not contain any zeroes in my code, is this what you are after ?

Comment: @Rockybilly No. I want to add some noise to non-zero element. 0 remains 0

Comment: Rafael has given the correct answer. Although it changes the nature of the noise, you can also multiply the Gaussian array with the original to preserve the zeroes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple selection problem

```
def gaussian_noise(X,sigma=0.1):
    X = np.array(X, dtype=np.float)
    M = X!=0
    noise = np.random.normal(0, sigma, X.shape)
    X[M] += noise[M]
    return X
```

will do